# extending fragments in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following fragment. I'm trying to extend the base fragment "head" with the open graph tags... but the rendered page contains only tags from fragments/head, with the og ones.

How can I add more tags to a fragment?

```
<head th:include="fragments/head :: head">
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags -->
    <meta property="og:url"         th:content="${url}" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="GUApp" />
    <meta property="og:description" th:content="${description}" />
    <!--<meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />-->
</head>

<head th:fragment="head" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
....
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to pass additional tags as in [Flexible layouts](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#flexible-layouts-beyond-mere-fragment-insertion) documentation demo.

> Thanks to fragment expressions, we can specify parameters for
>   fragments that are not texts, numbers, bean objects… but instead
>   fragments of markup.
>
> This allows us to create our fragments in a way such that they can be
>   enriched with markup coming from the calling templates, resulting in a
>   very flexible template layout mechanism.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head th:include="header :: head(~{::meta})">
        <!-- You can use Open Graph tags -->
        <meta property="og:url" th:content="${url}"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="GUApp"/>
        <meta property="og:description" th:content="${description}"/>
    </head>

...
```

**header.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head th:fragment="head(meta)">
        <!-- some default styles -->
        <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!--/* Per-page placeholder for additional meta tags */-->
        <th:block th:replace="${meta}" />
    </head>

...
```

Result html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta property="og:url"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="GUApp"/>
    <meta property="og:description"/>
</head>

...
```

Comment: It should works according to the docs, but...

Could not parse as fragment selection: "fragments/head :: head(~{::meta})" (concorso:4)

<head th:replace="fragments/head :: head(~{::meta})">
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags -->
    <meta property="og:url"         th:content="${url}" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="GUApp" />
    <meta property="og:description" th:content="${description}" />
    <!--<meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />-->
</head>

Comment: @Progeny are you using Thymeleaf 2? Because i think Flexible layouts available only in version 3. If you can't switch, can try [Parameterizable fragment signatures](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures) and path some `Map<'property', 'content'>`  instead of block of tags.